# Reporting rows based on unique values in 1 column

Tags: unique

I have a dataset (df1)

```
ID  DATE
1   10-April-2013
2   11-April-2013
3   12-April-2013
1   12-April-2013
2   13-April-2013
4   16-April-2013
```

I need to get 1 row/ID reporting the earliest DATE

```
ID  DATE
1   10-April-2013
2   11-April-2013
3   12-April-2013
4   16-April-2013

undf1 <- unique(df1[ ,c("ID","DATE")]) is not working since DATE is unique as well
```

I'd really appreciate any input here...

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT DATE, MAX(id) FROM df1 GROUP BY DATE
```